# Kill all the threads caused by hanging DLL Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dll, loadlibrary

I have a Delphi code which calls a DLL. 
DLL is dynamically linked.

In the beginning of my code i have the initiation/opening of DLL via

```
DllHandle:= LoadLibrary(DllFileName);
```

- In case DLL file does not exist I get a `DLLHandle=0`, which is good. And I can move on to my next line in the main program.
- In case DLL file exists and initialized correctly I get a `non-zero DLLHandle`, which is also good.

However every now and then something goes wrong INSIDE the DLL, meaning that the file exists but DLL is not reponsive.
So my main application is hanging.

To avoid this I looked into multi threading.

My main program  has a new type `TMyThread` inheriting from `TThread` and overrides `Create, Destroy, Execute`.

My main program creates a new thread (`ChildThread`) on the fly. ChildThread's  `Execute` method is calling the above mentioned LoadLibrary.

By doing so I can continue my main program and wait a bit to see if the `ChildThread` returns a non-zero DLLhandle.
If the DLLhandle in the ChildThread is stil zero after few seconds I would like to kill the thread and free the DLL and retry.

Investigating further I can see the list of Threads in Delphi IDE. Initially there are 4 threads under my main program. When I create the ChildTread a new one shows up. And few seconds after (when the Execute is called and the loadlibrary is called in the ChildTread) two more threads show up. I guess the main DLL is calling other threads.

At this stage I have no access to the ChildTread so I can not have a while loop in the Execute method to look if it is terminated or not and exit the thread. Because the actual code in that thread is already hanging in the execute.

QUESTION:
the `ChildTread` hangs but my main program continues. I want to kill the ChildThread (maybe all other threads it started) from my main  program and retry the
    DllHandle:= LoadLibrary(DllFileName);

Comment: This is the wrong solution. You can't make this work inside a single process. You need to move this into a separate process. You need the isolation that you get with a process.

Comment: is there a way to do that from within Delphi ?

Comment: Yeah, but it's not trivial. One option would be an out of process COM server. That takes care of all the IPC. I'd fix the DLL (or perhaps it's the way you are using it) if it were me though.

Comment: i dont get why killing a thread (or a simple function call) that i have created is so hard to kill. So within Delphi i know which thread IDs should be killed but can not kill?.

Comment: "*i dont get why killing a thread (or a simple function call) that i have created is so hard to kill*" --- Because nornally you do not simply "kill" threads.

Answer (score 1):

> My main program creates a new thread (ChildThread) on the fly. ChildThread's Execute method is calling the above mentioned LoadLibrary.

```
var thread := TMyThread.Create(...);
```

> At this stage I have no access to the ChildTread so I can not have a while loop in the Execute method to look if it is terminated or not and exit the thread. Because the actual code in that thread is already hanging in the execute.

```
if (thread <> nil) 
and DetectWhetherThreadIsHanging(thread)    // <- this is your code
then begin
  TerminateThread(thread.Handle,1);
  thread.Free;
end;
```

Not tested. Not even compiled. But something in that direction.

**Recommended reading**: [MSDN TerminateThread() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread)

> *TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination. For example, TerminateThread can result in the following problems [...]*

Finally, again: You do not simply kill threads. If the DLL gets stuck on loading, there is either a reason for it or a bug in the DLL. In 99% of all cases when one feels the need to "kill" a thread or a process for algorithmical reasons it is the wrong approach.

**EDIT and a possible workaround**

> but there are other threads that are called by the LoadLibrary(DLL). they are not killed. I think therefore the DLL is not freed so i can not call the loadlibrary(dll) again

The only real approach to something like a solution I could imagine is this, but it may not be a viable solution to you. It mainly depends on what the DLL does, but since you do not tell us we don't know.

1. wrap the DLL into a separate(!) EXE
2. start that EXE from the real program and have the second EXE terminate itself when it fails
3. repeat that process until you finally succeed
4. do whatever you have to do with that DLL in the second process and use some sort of IPC between the two processes.

Comment: 1- dll is external and fails because it can not reach the license sometimes. we can not change this
2- your suggestion kills the first thread that calls the DLL but there are other threads that are called by the LoadLibrary(DLL). they are not killed. I think therefore the DLL is not freed so i can not call the loadlibrary(dll) again

Comment: @user2375049 1- you need to contact the DLL author to fix that issue. The DLL should not be trying to contact or otherwise verify a license during its loading. That should be done after the DLL has been fully loaded first. A DLL's load logic should be kept to a minimum, there are only so many things that a DLL's entry point can legally/safely do.

Comment: @user2375049 2- there is no way to identify which module creates which thread. JensG suggests you kill YOUR thread that is loading the DLL. If the DLL itself creates additional threads, there is no reliable way to match those to the DLL and kill them, too. I mean, you could enumerate threads before loading the DLL, and then enumerate again afterwards, and then kill any new threads you detect, but there is no guarantee those are not just extra system threads created for your own process, for instance.

Comment: "*your suggestion kills the first thread that calls the DLL*" - I know, but I followed the statements (and cited them) made in the problem description. I never claimed it will kill all threads. And I discourage you from even considering this code, yet still I give it to you. Because you may learn something.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Agree. That was never the idea. I only answered the question.